# Convert rtf to xaml in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I want to load a rtf file in silverlight using RichTextBox control but this control doesn't load file in proper format. can anyone tell how to do so or convert rtf to xaml?

Here's the xaml :

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="480" Width="640">
            <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,64,0,0" Name="rtb" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="301" Width="416"/>
            <Button Content="Select File" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="268,12,0,0" Name="btnSelect" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnSelect_Click" />
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="FileName:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,12,0,0" Name="txtFile" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" />
            <Button Content="Reset" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="430,385,0,0" Name="btnReset" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnReset_Click" IsEnabled="False" />
        </Grid>


Code behind :

private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog odlg = new OpenFileDialog();

            odlg.Filter = "Text files|*.rtf";
            odlg.Multiselect = false;
            string contents = null;

            if ((bool)odlg.ShowDialog())
            {
                txtFile.Text = odlg.File.Name;

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(odlg.File.OpenRead());
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                reader.Close();

                rtb.Selection.Text = contents;
                btnReset.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtFile.Text = "";
            rtb.Blocks.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: Please include a short code example of where you load the file.

Comment: _ but this control doesn't load file in proper format_ - Yes it does.

Comment: May be then i m missing something in my code.. i have uploaded my code. When i upload any rtf file, it doesn't get loaded in format specified in rtf document.. Please can u check my code and suggest a solution.?

Comment: Henk if it does, then can u pls give me a sample code for uploading.. I need it urgently in my project... Thanks..!!

Comment: Can anyone please suggest a solution to this problem?